# Mongoose retrieving all the oject values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to retrieve all of the object values from an mongoose schema for example:

```
{
 id: 553a75a7e4b092e5edad4bce,
 name: Jeff,
 name1: Ricky,
 name2: Lexi,
 name3: Eric
} I'm expecting Jeff Ricky Lexi Eric
```

I used the following:

```
{
    Name.find(function(err, s){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      mongoose.connection.close();

      Object.values(s).forEach(val=>{

      console.log(val));
      });

    }
  });
}
```

But I got this instead:

```
{
 id: 553a75a7e4b092e5edad4bce,
 name: Jeff,
 name1: Ricky,
 name2: Lexi,
 name3: Eric
}
```

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose find method is not returning a single object but an array of objects.

If you wany to display values from them you can try using nested loops. Something like this should work

```
{
    Name.find(function(err, s){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      mongoose.connection.close();
      
      s.forEach(obj => {
        Object.values(obj).forEach(val=>{

        console.log(val));
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Just keep in mind that you would display every property of all returned objects.